# Lagrange multipliers method for a bead on a parabola-shaped wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, simulations, constrained-dynamics, software

I have this simulation problem that looks very easy at first look (and maybe it is, especially using Lagrange equations of the 2nd. kind). I am using the Lagrange multipliers and I am kinda not sure where exactly the issue is. I am using Julia programming language to simulate the movement of a very simple system: a bead of mass *m* that is constrained to move frictionlessly on a parabola in the xy-plane under the influence of gravity. The y-axis is directed upwards, the gravity downwards. The equations of motion are:
$$\mathbf{f}+\mathbf{f_c} = m\mathbf{a}$$
where $$\mathbf{f_c} = \lambda\cdot\nabla g$$
the constraint force, and $g=g(y,x)=y-x^2$ corresponds to the constraint. $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier.
The code is:

```
λ = 1.0
x = 1.0
y = x^2  #initial height
vx = 0.1  #initial horizontal velocity
vy = 0.0  #initial vertical velocity
t_max = 30.0
h = 0.01  #time step

#initialize arrays for position
x_values = [x]
y_values = [y]

t = 0.0
while t < t_max
    #the constraint force components
    f_cx = -λ * 2 * x
    f_cy = λ
    
    #gravity components
    f_x = 0.0
    f_y = -m * g
    
    #acceleration components
    ax = (f_x + f_cx) / m
    ay = (f_y + f_cy) / m
    
    #update velocities
    vx += ax * h
    vy += ay * h
    
    #update positions
    x += vx * h + 0.5 * ax * h^2
    y += vy * h + 0.5 * ay * h^2
    
    #current position
    push!(x_values, x)
    push!(y_values, y)
    
    #incrementing time
    t += h
end
```

This code (with the plotting code, that's not shown here), and as I expect from the constrained motion above, should produce a path that looks like a parabola. Why doesn't it? I am getting a falling bead instead. Also at the bottom of the parabola should $\mathbf{f_{c}}_y=mg$, so that $a_y  = 0$ at that point. Is this problem even solvable using this method?

Comment: $~\lambda~$ is unknown, you must obtained it first

Answer (score 1):

Observe that depending where the bead is on the parabola, the constraint force of the parabola changes its direction and magnitude. That magnitude is related to $\lambda$. So lambda changes with time. Hence, you need to evolve $[x, y, v_x, v_y, \lambda]$ with time.

The equations of motion can be written as follows:
\begin{align}
& y - x^2 = 0\\
&\\
&\frac{dx}{dt} \,=\,v_x \\
&\\
&\frac{dy}{dt} \,=\, v_y\\
&\\
&\frac{dv_x}{dt} \,=\, -2x\lambda \\
&\\
&\frac{dv_y}{dt} \,=\, -\,g \,+\, \lambda
\end{align}
where the variables to be propagated in time are $x,\,y, \, \lambda$.

An algorithm can be based on the following idea: given the current $\,x_n, y_n, v_{x,n}, v_{y,n}$ calculate the next $\,x_{n+1}, y_{n+1}, v_{x,n+1}, v_{y,n+1}$ by solving the system of algebraic equations for the unknown variables $\,x_{n+1}, y_{n+1}, , v_{x,n+1}, v_{y,n+1}, \lambda_{n+1}\,$:
\begin{align}
&\,  \Big(\,y_n + \Delta t\,v_{y,n} -  {\Delta t^2}\,g \, +\,  {\Delta t^2}\,\lambda_{n+1}\,\Big)\,-\,\Big(\, x_n + \Delta t\,v_{x,n} - \Delta t^2\,{2\,x_n}\,\lambda_{n+1}\,\Big)^2 \,=\, 0\\
&v_{x,n+1} \,=\, v_{x,n} - {\Delta t}\,{2\,x_n}\,\lambda_{n+1}\\
&v_{y,n+1} \,=\, v_{y,n} - {\Delta t}\,g \, +\, {\Delta t}\,\lambda_{n+1} \\
&x_{n+1} \,=\, x_n + \Delta t\,v_{x,n+1}\\
&y_{n+1} \,=\, y_n + \Delta t\,v_{y,n+1}
\end{align}
Things are even simpler: first, you just have to solve the first quadratic equation for $\lambda_{n+1}$ - the latter variable is the only unknown in that equation. After that, you simply use the solution $\lambda_{n+1}$ in the second and the third equation to obtain directly the new $\,v_{x,n+1}, v_{y,n+1}$, after which, you find the new $\,x_{n+1}, y_{n+1}$. Loop.